# How do I use an ID throughout a Delphi app

Tags: delphi

I have a MySql database which has a users table and all the other tables are connected to the users table.

If we log in to an user that has id = 1. We want to make all the requests to mysql using the user_id = 1, so it'll be displayed only the data from this specific user.

I have a login screen in my Delphi app where the user can type his username and password. After a successfully login I want to take thie user_id to use and throughout this application to make the calls. How should I do it?

After the login in successfully, should I sotre this ID in Delphi somehow and access it whenever we want to make some call? If so, how do I save this id in Delphi so I can use it in several forms?

Comment: Easiest to add a DataModule to your project and store the ID as a member field of it.  You could also include the non-gui dv components and code for looking up the ID there, and for all your other db operations.  You would then USE your dtamodule's unit in your other units.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A way to do this is to add a DataModule to your project and make the `UserID` a
field of this.

So, using Delphi's default naming, you would have

```
type
  TDataModule1 = class(TDataModule)
  [...]
  public
    property UserID : Integer read FUserID;
  end;

  [...]
  var
    DataModule1 : TDataModule1;
```

Then, add to TDataModule1 the db-access components your project uses, e.g. a Query
component to access the Users table where user details are stored and a method to
try to login in a given user, and also a db-connection component of the type your db-access components use.  So you could add a method like this:

```
  function TDataModule1.LogInUser(const UserName : String) : Boolean;
  begin
    try
      if qUsers.Active then
        qUsers.Close;
      FUserID := -1; // deliberately set an invalid UserID
      Assert(Trim(UserName) <> ''));  // raise exception if UserName is blank
      //  qUsers Sql.Text property would be something like 'select * from users where username = :username'
      qUsers.ParamByName(UserName).Value := UserName;
      qUsers.Open;
      if qUsers.Locate('UserName', UserName, []) then
        FUserID := qUsers.FieldByName('UserID').AsInteger;
    finally
      Result := FUserID >= 0;  // assuming   zero is a valid UserID
    end;
  end;
```

and save the module under the name, say, of `DataModule1u`.  Notice that this method omits any reference to the user's password:  This is because if you leave your db connection component's `LoginPrompt` property at the default `True` value, it will pop up a prompt for the user's password when the `LogInUser` method executes.

Once you've got that far, go to your Login form's unit and edit it to USE `DataModule1u`.

Then you can add code to it to use the `LogInUser` method like so:

```
   if DataModule1.LogInUser(UserName) then begin

     Caption := 'User: ' + IntToStr(DataModule1.UserID);
     //  do something else with DataModule1.UserID's value
   end;
```

Obviously you could (and usually should) add all your db-access components to the datamodule
and USE it in your forms which do db-access.

Hope this is all clear, if not then ask.

Comment: I didn't think about that :|. This'll definitely work. Thank u so much!!

Comment: Should I also place my DataSource and all FD widgets in the DataModule?

Comment: Up to you.  Usually, I would put DataSources on the form where they are used.  Non-gui widgets of whatever sort can also be in a DM.  DMs were added to Delphi to act as a centralised repository of any sort of non-gui component or member, not just db-access ones.

Comment: @MartynA There is a bug to be aware of. Be sure to name your datamodules. (Don't use default names) The problem is: If you use a project group, and 2 projects have a datamodule with the same name, and you open forms that use those data modules, the datasource properties of the data aware components on the forms will be blanked by the IDE.

Comment: This is an easy solution, but not as easy as making it a global, while there isn't that much difference, because you made it a property of a global... Unfortunately it's a common anti pattern, fed by the fact that Delphi is making global variables for every form and data module.

Comment: At some point you won't be happy anymore with a big, overly smart global datamodule. If you continue with that, I would at least start by splitting it in two parts: One class holding the current state of the session (user id, etc), and another one for running the queries and setting the state. The first is a global/singleton-like object, but is dumb and just keeps state. The latter has the logic, but is a stateless utility class. By splitting it like this, you have made it already a bit easier for that day in the future when you want to refactor the app and apply inversion of control (IoC).